# Alternative for `\linebreak` in inline math mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, breqn

Looking at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119266/penalty-10000-or-linebreak/119371#119371) and the chat that followed it, I was wondering what would be considered best practise to include line breaks in inline math mode (breqn does not quite work; there's some problem with the unicode support, and even breqn doesn't resolve all the problems so some manual optimisation does always seem to be required if you have a lot of inline equations araound text).

The minimal working example is by no means small, but I tried to get rid  of everything that is not related to the question. The problem is that removing one of my definitions in the preamble will alter the layout of specific lines and therefore the line breaking "errors" won't be reproducible. Well, here it is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% basic
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

\parindent = 0px
\parskip = 10px

\def\labelitemi{‒}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0px}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

% bidirektionaler Äquivalenzbeweis
\newlength{\beweispfeil}
\settowidth{\beweispfeil}{\enquote{\( \implies \quad \)}}

\newlist{beweis}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[beweis]{leftmargin=\beweispfeil}

% Äquivalenz durch beidseitige Inklusion
\newlength{\inklusionszeichen}
\settowidth{\inklusionszeichen}{\enquote{\(\subseteq\quad\)}}

\newlist{inklusion}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[inklusion]{leftmargin=\inklusionszeichen}

\newcommand*\setdiff{\mathbin{∖}}
\newcommand*\qed{\quad\square}
\newcommand*\sem{\mathrel{\mathop{;}}}
\newcommand*\wid{\quad\lightning}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Loes}{Lös}

\newcommand*\ordpair[2]{\left( #1, #2 \right)}
\newcommand*\struct[2]{\(\ordpair{#1}{#2}\)}
\newcommand*\field{\struct{K}{+, \cdot}}
\newcommand*\restr[2]{#1_{\left|#2\right.}}
\newcommand*\LoesG{\Loes \left(\left(\alpha_{j_k}\right)_{\substack{1 \leq j \leq m\\1 \leq k \leq n}} \sem 0\right)} % Solution to a general system of linear equations

\newcommand*\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand*\R{\mathbb{R}}

% Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Zeilenabstände
\linespread{1.15}

\newcounter{einschub}[chapter]

% Festlegungen für Nummerierungsumgebungen
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\roman*), leftmargin=*, widest=viii, parsep=1ex}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=\alph*), leftmargin=*, parsep=1ex}

\setenumerate[0]{label=\roman*)}

\begin{document}

Es sei \field{} ein Körper, \( U \subseteq K \). Danh heißt \(U\) Unterkörper von \field, wenn
\struct{U}{\restr{+}{U \times U}, \restr{\cdot}{U \times U}} ein Körper ist.

Weiter gilt \( \forall \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) \in K^n : \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) + \left(0, \dots, 0 \right) = \left(x_1+0, \dots, x_n+0 \right)
= \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) \), also ist \( \left(0, \dots, 0 \right) \in K^n \) ein rechtsneutrales Element bezüglich \(+\) und
\( \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) \in K^n : \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) + \left(-x_1, \dots, -x_n \right) = \left(x_1+\left(-x_1\right), \dots, x_n+\left(-x_n\right) \right)
= \left(0, \dots, 0 \right) \), sodass \( \left(-x_1, \dots, -x_n \right) \) ein Rechtsinverses zu \( \left(x_1, \dots, x_n \right) \) bezüglich \( \left(0, \dots, 0 \right) \) ist.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Sei \(V\) ein \(K\)-Vektorraum und \(x \in V\).

\begin{itemize}
\item Damit ist \(p+q\) eine Polynomfunktion (mit Koeffizienten \( \lambda_0 + \nu_0, \dots, \lambda_m + \nu_m,
\lambda_{m+1}, \dots, \lambda_n\)), also \(p+q\in K[\alpha]\).
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{inklusion}
\item[\enquote{\( \subseteq \)}] Seien \( x_1, \dots, x_{n+1} \in A, \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{n+1} \in K \). Nach Induktionsvoraussetzung gilt \( \sum _{k=1} ^n \alpha_k x_k \in \Span A \).
\end{inklusion}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Wir setzen \( \LoesG \coloneqq \left\{ (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \in \R^n, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_n \text{ sind Lösungen von (\star)} \right\} \) die Menge aller Lösungen von (\star). Dann ist \( \LoesG \) ein Unterraum von \(\R^n\), denn (mit Äquivalenzsatz):

Setzt man \( a_1 \coloneqq \left(\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha_{m1}\end{smallmatrix}\right), \dots, a_n \coloneqq \left(\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha_{mn}\end{smallmatrix}\right) \) und schreibt man die Elemente von \(\R^m\) als Spalten anstatt als Zeilen, so gilt \( a_1, \dots, a_n \in \R^n \) und \( \left(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\right) \in \LoesG \) genau dann, wenn
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Behauptung: \( x_1, \dots, x_n \) linear abhängig \( \iff \exists j \in \left\{ 1, \dots, n \right\} : x_j
\text{ Linearkombination}
\text{ von } x_1, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_m \).

\begin{beweis}
\item[\enquote{\( \implies \)}] \( x_1, \dots, x_m \) linear abhängig \( \implies \exists (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \in K^m \setdiff \left\{0\right\} : 0 = \sum _{l=1} ^m \xi_l x_l \)

Wegen \((\xi_1, \dots, \xi_m) \neq (0, \dots, 0)\) existiert \( j \in \left\{ 1, \dots, m \right\} \) mit \( \xi_j \neq 0 \implies 0 = \xi_j ^{-1} \cdot 0 = \xi_j ^{-1} \cdot \sum _{l=1} ^m \xi_l x_l = \xi_j ^{-1} \xi_1 x_1 + \dots + \xi_j ^{-1} \xi_{j-1} x_{j-1} + x_j + \xi_j ^{-1} \xi_{j+1} x_{j+1}
+ \dots + \xi_j ^{-1} \xi_m x_m \implies  x_j = \left(-\xi_j ^{-1} \xi_1\right) x_1 + \dots + \left(-\xi_j ^{-1} \xi_{j-1}\right) x_{j-1} +
\left(-\xi_j ^{-1} \xi_{j+1}\right) x_{j+1} + \dots + \left(-\xi_j ^{-1} \xi_m\right) x_m \), also ist \(x_j\) Linearkombination von \( x_1, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_m \).
\end{beweis}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{beweis}
\item[\enquote{\( \implies \)}] Beweis: Angenommen, \( \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \} \cap \{ y_1, \dots, y_m \} \neq \emptyset \implies x_1, \dots, x_n,
y_1, \dots, y_m \) paarweise verschieden und nach (\star) gilt \( 0 = x - x = \sum _{j=1} ^n \alpha_j x_j + \sum _{k=1} ^m (-\beta_k) y_k \implies \alpha_1 = \dots = \alpha_n = -\beta_1 = \dots = -\beta_m = 0 \), da \(A\) linear unabhängig ist. \(\wid_{b_{k_0}\neq0}\)

Mit dieser Hilfsbehauptung können wir nach eventueller Umnummerierung von
\( x_1, \dots, x_n \) annehmen, dass es \( l \in \{ 1, \dots, n \} \) gibt mit \( \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \} \in \{ y_1, \dots, y_m \} \), \( \{ x_{l+1}, \dots, x_n \}
\cap \{ y_1, \dots, y_m \} = \emptyset \) und \( x_j = y_j \) für alle \( 1 \leq j \leq l \).
\end{beweis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not come out clearly enough. We are talking inline equations here, where the commands you mentioned do not work.

Comment: You can try lowering `\binoppenalty` and `\relpenalty`. Can you add a small “typical” example?