# Is there something like a would-rather-not-break space in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I know that `~` prevents line breaks and that   allows them.
Is there something in between to tell LaTeX that it *could* break here if necessary, but it would be better not to.

For example "in order to", "so that", etc. are easier to read if on the same line (at least to me).

Comment: see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262408/36296 helps

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes thank you