Definition of nobreak changed after upgrade to TexLive2024
We have now updated our Linux system and therefore upgraded as well to lualatex 1.18.0. Somehow the definition of nobreak seems to have changed - or at least the handle of it. Since we're running Unit-tests I can see there is an additional space introduced when using the nobreak command. MWE
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel}
\newcommand{\nbsp}{\nobreak%
    \hspace{.16667em plus .08333em}
}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for rules within a table
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ X X}
    \midrule[1pt]
    \bfseries Lorem ipsum test &\nbsp{}\\
    \midrule[1pt]
    {\selectlanguage{naustrian}Ein Vergleich mit der alten Version}
    &\nbsp{}\\
    \midrule[1pt]
    \addlinespace[1pt]\midrule[1pt]
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}

The command nbsp should introduce just a single space which is not allowed to break the content before and after. The given definition worked perfectly in 1.17, running in 1.18 I get an extra line introduced (marked with red).

When I comment the nobreak command than the layout seems fine, i.e. no additional line introduced. Honestly I have not enough skills to pinpoint to the source of this problem - either xltabular or LaTeX or... I would guess this is a bug and not a feature ;-)
Anyway is there a way to fix with the current version? Just using \penalty 10000 won't change anything.

This is user error, \nobreak is not a latex commandreally it is a holdover from plain tex and if used in vertical mode (as here in some versions) it prevents page breaking not line breaking. use \leavevmode\nolinebreak also note that a final skip in a tabular cell is always removed so you may want to use a guard after the skip.  why define \nobsp rather than the standard \nobreakspace or ~ ?

I'm aware that updating a given example is normally not a very good idea. Honestly I don't know if posting a newer post would clarify the issue more. :-/ The problem persists when now using babel package. The suggested solutions to use nobreakspace won't work neither. For the table itself I agree I could use the other commands - but when using babel than ???

nobreakspace starts \leavevmode so I'd expect it to work

It works - same as \nobreakspace or ~ - when changing the definition of the macro. But as soon as I change the language a line break is introduced. Which was not there in 1.17

Updating an example is bad if it invalidates existing answers.  If the update you're thinking of wouldn't change the question all that much, then I'd say go for it.

the example uses babel and, as expected, the extra line goes if you use \leavevmode before \nobreak  or if you had used \nobreakspace instead of defining a custom command.  There is also a % missing in the definition of \nobsp

Thx for pointing out the missing % in the definition although it won't change anything. I've tried right now with simply replacing the usage of the command with \nobreakspace as well as changing the definition into \newcommand{\nbsp}{\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{.16667em plus .08333em}}. But somehow the results are all the same namely the line persists :-/ Would you mind to post your suggestion in an own answer? I can post mine as well - but this won't solve the issue.

\nobreak (which shouldn't be used in latex, it's just carried over from plain tex, has not changed. What has changed is that more often at the start of p columns tex is in vertical mode. In vmode \break prevents page breaking not line breaking so does nothing useful here. You could prefix by \leavevmode so that the penalty always occurs in hmode and prevents line breaks, or (better) use the standard \nobreakspace command rather than defining a substitute.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel}
\newcommand{\nbsp}{\leavevmode\nobreak%
    \hspace{.16667em plus .08333em}%<<<<<<<
}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for rules within a table
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ X X}
    \midrule[1pt]
    \bfseries Lorem ipsum test &\nbsp{}\\
    \midrule[1pt]
    {\leavevmode\selectlanguage{naustrian}Ein Vergleich mit der alten Version}
    &\nbsp{}\\
    \midrule[1pt]
    \addlinespace[1pt]\midrule[1pt]
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}

Produces

without the \leavevmode you get

UPDATE Using \leavevmode before \selectlanguage in this example prevents adding an additional line before Ein Vergleich mit der alten Version.

Thx for summarizing your solution. My only persisting problem is that the empty line before Ein Vergleich mit der alten Version was NOT there in 1.17

@LeO you didn't ask about that space (which has the same solution, put \leavevmode before it)

Hmmm... first of all thx for your help and providing a solution. For me the title of this topic was clear enough - namely that with the new version the behaviour is changed. Could be a fix for something which was broken before OR could be a newly introduced bug. I don't know and I am unable to determine.

Using the command nobreakspace sounds reasonable. Adding \leavemode sucks - since it adds complexity for my conversion. Anyway - I've read that nobreak is deprecated in LaTeX - fine. Is this bit of information somewhere accessible or is it just because you're knowing the code (quite well)? More or less: Where can I find that kind of info on my own?

but you circled a space in the output and I showed how to fix that, but then you asked about a different space in a different row that did not have \nobreak at all, but even on the row with a \nobreak  the problem is not that \nobreak had changed. but no harm done:-)

it's not so much that \nobreak is deprecated, it simply is not mentioned in the latex manual. the latex book only tells you about \nolinebreak and ~ and either of those would have worked. If you look in the latex sources and find undocumented internal commands such as \nobreak then you use at your own risk.

but searching this site might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94217/what-is-the-difference-between-nobreak-and-nolinebreak/94220#94220

I’m not sure, but I think it’s related to https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/284.

@JavierBezos well yes in that it's https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/284#issuecomment-1944208032  in that previously you would see this behaviour if array was loaded but now you also see it without. but that issue was mor about otherlanguage whereas this is using \selectlanguage directly
